# Compiling problems with shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I try to compile some code, which works on my main-pc under ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Now I want to use a little board(Zedboard) with linux to control a EnOceanreceiver.
I use Linaro 12.11 and programm in C++.

If I compile, there is no error. But if I want to start the programm comes:
error while loading shared libraries: libEOLink.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

My Makefile looks like:

```
all: EnOcean.cpp
   g++ -I/homelinaro/EOLink EnOcean.cpp -o EnOcean -L/usr/local/lib -lEOLink
```

I found the data under /usr/local/lib but it doesn't help if with or not.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

If libEOLink.so.0 can be found in /usr/local/lib, you shouldn't need to add it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as this should already be part of the path. It's possible that library relies on other librari(es) that are not found. To determine whether this is the case, run:

`ldd /usr/local/lib/libEOLink.so.0`

If any dependencies are not found, it will be reported.

I also assume you combiled libEOLink for your target system.

Comment: I got back:  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6e2e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6dc2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6cde000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f19000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6cbc000) But I have this data. But what says the hex-number? /usr/lib/local/lib is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH too.

Comment: That's the load address of the library, and isn't really important for your purposes. Just to verify, you did build libEOLink.so.0 for your target ARM architecture, right?

Comment: Hi, it works now. I tipped this again(I don't know if this was the solution) ->sudo sh -c 'echo SUBSYSTEMS==\"usb\", KERNEL==\"ttyUSB?\", ATTRS{interface}==\"EnOcean USB300 ??\",MODE=\"0666\", SYMLINK+=\"USB300\" > /etc/udev/rules.d/70-enocean-stick.rules'
 ->sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
 ->sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0